# Print elements of ruby array line by line after splitting a single string with "\n" condition

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, stringstream

I have a single string, achieved using backticks of the following form:

```
output = `git log`
```

then, I have splitted the result where there are "\n" and the result went into an array of the form:

```
array = output.split("\n")
```

then, I am just trying to output the result in the screen, however, when I am using

```
array.each do |a|
    puts a
end
```

I am getting as a result a double line of the form:

```
result after puts
(empty line)
result after puts etc
```

when my preferred result is a single line of the form:

```
result after puts
result afters puts etc
```

I tried to perform this with print, but I am getting:

```
result after puts result after puts etc
```

in a single line.

Can you please help me?

Comment: `puts array` will do the right thing, it will print it with the new line see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-puts `If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you split using `\n`, if there are two `\n` characters then an empty `""` gets added to the array.

```
eg: test = ["this","","is","test"]
```

Now if you do,

```
test.each do |a|
    puts a
end

The o/p will be,

this
// a new line will come here.
is
test
```

so you should reject the empty values,

```
test2 = test.reject{ |value| value == ""}

  test2.each do |a|
        puts a
    end
```

Result is,

```
  this
  is
  test
```

In same way,

```
output = `git log`

array = output.split("\n")

array2 = array.reject{ |value| value == ""}

array2.each do |a|
    puts a
end
```

This will give you the correct result.

Comment: `The issue is when you split using \n if there are two \n characters then an empty "" gets added to the array`. Howcome? `a = "1\n2\n3\n4\n"; a.split("\n") #=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]`

Comment: @hack-is-art see the comments to your question

Comment: @AndreyDeineko can you provide me with code please?

Comment: `a = "1\n\n2\n3\n4\n"; a.split("\n")`

Comment: @hack-is-art, if you added my code, pls paste array and array2.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Thank you, the answer is slightly different that the one you gave, it is: array.each {|array|}

Comment: Yes, I posted the answer mentioning your name and your comment. Thank you so much mate!

Comment: @hack-is-art I think you should just do `puts aray`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko yes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AndreyDeineko, we have that:

"The issue is when you split using \n if there are two \n characters then an empty "" gets added to the array. Howcome? a = "1\n2\n3\n4\n"; a.split("\n") #=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"].

Therefore, array.each `{ |a| a }` will work for you"

It did not work 100% for me, but using his answer, I manage to achieve the required result which is:

```
array.each { |a| a }
    puts array
```